# Mysql simplify query to stay without subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

in my database I have stored errors:

```
+----+---------------------+----------+-------------------+
| id | date                | message  | name              |
+----+---------------------+----------+-------------------+
|  2 | 2018-07-17 11:01:52 | message2 | TypeError         |
|  1 | 2018-07-14 11:01:52 | message  | HttpErrorResponse |
|  3 | 2018-07-19 11:01:52 | message3 | HttpErrorResponse |
|  4 | 2018-07-19 11:01:52 | message4 | UriError          |
+----+---------------------+----------+-------------------+
```

I want to create another table which contains daily raports:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------------+
| day         | htttpErrors | TypeErrors        |OtherErrors:
+---------------------+----------+--------------+
| 2018-07-17  | 1           | 3                 |     0
| 2018-07-18  | 2           | 0                 |     5
```

How to do it in best way?
Of course I can do something like this:

```
 SELECT  
    current_date(), 
    (select count(*) from error where day=current_date() and name=TypeErrors)
.........
    FROM error
```

but is there cleaner way?

PS. sorry for the tittle - I have no idea how to name it properly.

Comment: So you want a simplified query for daily reports instead of creating a table?

Comment: table for daily raport is created :) Sorry I can said this uncleary

Comment: Can you clarify which is the *daily report* table in your question?

Comment: this is the second one :)

Comment: What's wrong with subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a SQL like below.

```
select  date(`date`) as day,
        sum(case when upper(name) like '%HTTP%' then 1 else 0 end) http_errors,
        sum(case when upper(name) like '%TYPE%' then 1 else 0 end) type_errors,
        sum(case when upper(name) not like '%HTTP%' and upper(name) not like '%TYPE%' then 1 else 0 end) other_errors, 
from error group by date(`date`);
```

Comment: Note that case sensitive collations seem quite rare in MySQL.